# React cannot resolve module in my directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django

[image: this is how my current react-app looks like]

this is how my react app looks like right now. So I want to import the CSS file `app_style.css` into `status_bar.jsx`
How can I do this?
When I try importing the file like this

```py
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '.../static/css/app_style.css'
```

I get the following error:

```py
Compiling...
Failed to compile.

./src/components/general_interface/status_bar.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '.../static/css/app_style.css' in 'C:\Users\iyapp\OneDrive\Desktop\python projects\PixSirius\PixSirius\react-app\src\components\general_interface'
Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?
Also, I am using Django for the backend.
This is my static_files configuration:

```py
# settings.py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'react-app/src/static'),
]
```

Is there any better area/ way to store my static CSS files and import them into react-js?
Please help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: you have extra dot in import Can't resolve '.../static/css/app_style.css'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your directory path is wrong. Three dots (".../") is not a valid relative path. It should be:

```
import '../../static/css/app_style.css'
```

Answer (score 0):

it is:

`import '../../static/css/app_style.css'`